# Override label and icon color inside elevatedbutton.icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to override the label and icon color inside an ElevatedButton.icon in Flutter.

In my form, I got a checkbox which when false the button is supposed to be disabled so I want to change the color but until now, the override doesn't seems to work.

```
ElevatedButton facebookIconButtonWithBool(BuildContext context, bool isSwitched, enableDisableElevatedButton()) {
   return ElevatedButton.icon(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.facebook,
        color: ColorConstants.teal600,
        size: 26,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        if (isSwitched == false) {
          enableDisableElevatedButton();
        } else
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
      },
      label: Text(
        'Facebook',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: ColorConstants.teal600,
          fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
      ),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
          (states) => Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 48),
        ),
        side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (isSwitched == false) {
              return BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.gray500);
            }
            return BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.teal600);
          },
        ),
        textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<TextStyle>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (isSwitched == false) {
              return TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.gray500);
            }
            return TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.teal600);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (isSwitched == false) {
              return ColorConstants.gray500;
            }
            return Colors.white10;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I don't have any override on the theme section, and when I'm using the switch, the textStyle is not working at all. (Side and BackgoundColor works fine otherwise)

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

```
OutlinedButton facebookIconButtonWithBoolTest(BuildContext context, bool isSwitched, enableDisableElevatedButton()) {
return OutlinedButton.icon(
  label: Text('Woolha.com'),
  icon: Icon(Icons.web),
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: isSwitched ? ColorConstants.teal600 : ColorConstants.gray500,
      side: isSwitched ? BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.teal600) : BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.gray500)),
  onPressed: () {
    if (isSwitched == false) {
      enableDisableElevatedButton();
    } else
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
  },
);
```

I change the elevatedButton by a outlinedButton and it works fine.